# How to indicate the browser that js file has changed and without refreshing it will reflect on client side. So it downloads the new copy?

Tags: javascript, grunt-contrib-watch

when changes occurs in JS file then it will reflect on client side immediately without refreshing and will clear the cache. How can I achieve this? one way is Grunt if you know another another way please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use gulp or grunt these are the javascript task runner they watch the js file and if any change in any js file it immediately reload the page

**Gulp**

https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp

https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js

**Grunt**

http://mattbailey.io/a-beginners-guide-to-grunt-redux/

Comment: Thanks @Hinganikar i want exact this